# how to use loop to do linear regression in R

Tags: r, loops, regression

I wonder if I can use such as for loop or apply function to do the linear regression in R. I have a data frame containing variables such as crim, rm, ad, wd. I want to do simple linear regression of crim on each of other variable.

Thank you!

Comment: Great question! It would be considerably easier if you could provide a [minimal](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [reproducible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) example for us to quickly play with to give you a suggestion.

Comment: There are too many directions to take with this question. Please edit your question with the response and predictors, and provide a set of reproducible example as well as the desired outcome for the loops.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you *really* want to do this, it's pretty trivial with `lapply()`, where we use it to "loop" over the other columns of `df`. A custom function takes each variable in turn as `x` and fits a model for that covariate.

```
df <- data.frame(crim = rnorm(20), rm = rnorm(20), ad = rnorm(20), wd = rnorm(20))

mods <- lapply(df[, -1], function(x, dat) lm(crim ~ x, data = dat))
```

`mods` is now a list of `lm` objects. The `names` of `mods` contains the names of the covariate used to fit the model. The main negative of this is that all the models are fitted using a variable `x`. More effort could probably solve this, but I doubt that effort is worth the time.

If you are just selecting models, which may be dubious, there are other ways to achieve this. For example via the **leaps** package and its `regsubsets` function:

```
library("leapls")
a <- regsubsets(crim ~ ., data = df, nvmax = 1, nbest = ncol(df) - 1)
summa <- summary(a)
```

Then `plot(a)` will show which of the models is "best", for example.

#### Original

If I understand what you want (`crim` is a covariate and the other variables are the responses you want to predict/model using `crim`), then you don't need a loop. You can do this using a matrix response in a standard `lm()`.

Using some dummy data:

```
df <- data.frame(crim = rnorm(20), rm = rnorm(20), ad = rnorm(20), wd = rnorm(20))
```

we create a matrix or multivariate response via `cbind()`, passing it the three response variables we're interested in. The remaining parts of the call to `lm` are entirely the same as for a univariate response:

```
mods <- lm(cbind(rm, ad, wd) ~ crim, data = df)
mods 

> mods

Call:
lm(formula = cbind(rm, ad, wd) ~ crim, data = df)

Coefficients:
             rm        ad        wd      
(Intercept)  -0.12026  -0.47653  -0.26419
crim         -0.26548   0.07145   0.68426
```

The `summary()` method produces a standard `summary.lm` output for each of the responses.

Comment: I am sorry I did not make it clear I want to use crim as response and other variables as predictors. And do a series of simple regression, such as crim~ad, crim~wd, crim~rm

Comment: You can do that by creating a formulas list: `formulas <- list(crim ~ rm, crim ~ ad, crim ~ wd)`. Then use `lapply` to fit the model.

Comment: @lacfo I've updated the answer to address this clarification.

Comment: There is also `nlme::lmList` which provides nice syntax and its own `summary` and `coef` methods, but requires reshaping the data.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you want to have response variable fix as first column of your data frame and you want to run simple linear regression multiple times individually with other variable keeping first variable fix as response variable.

h=iris[,-5]

```
for (j in 2:ncol(h)){
  assign(paste("a", j, sep = ""),lm(h[,1]~h[,j]))
}
```

Above is the code which will create multiple list of regression output and store it in a2,a3,....