# Running multiple Kruskal Wallis test with lapply taking long. Easier solution?

Tags: r, large-data, kruskal-wallis

I have a data frame 90 observations and 124306 variables named KWR all numeric data. I want to run a Kruskal Wallis analysis within every column between groups. I added a vector with every different group behind my variables named "Group". To test the accuracy, I tested one peptide (named x2461) with this code:

```
kruskal.test(X2461 ~ Group, data = KWR)
```

Which worked out fine and got me a result instantly. However, I need all the variables to be analyzed. I used lapply while reading this post: [How to loop Bartlett test and Kruskal tests for multiple columns in a dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63293995/how-to-loop-bartlett-test-and-kruskal-tests-for-multiple-columns-in-a-dataframe)

```
cols <- names(KWR)[1:124306]
allKWR <- lapply(cols, function(x) kruskal.test(reformulate("Group", x), data = KWR))
```

However, after 2 hours of R working non stop, I quit the job. Is there any more efficient way of doing this?

Thanks in advance.

NB: first time poster, beginner in R

Comment: You can decide to only store p-values.  
You can also decide to parallelize your code so it runs X times faster, for example if you have 4 cores, you can run the code on 3 cores so it runs 3 times faster.

Comment: Still keep in mind that you are performing more than 100.000 tests! So I would suggest you start with maybe the first 100 columns and check how long this takes. Then repeat with the first 1000 columns and check again. This should give you a good estimate of how long it runs with 126k tests. Your code itself is fine (except the option of parallelizing it as suggested  above).

Comment: @YacineHajji How would you be able to only store p values? Or parallelize your code? Is parallelizing this as simple as using splitting cols in cols 1/cols2/cols3 and assigning 1/3 of the data.frame to these? As I said, I'm new to R, I did a short R course and mainly search on stack overflow for answers.

Comment: You can store p-values (if you only need p-values, and I believe so as you have 100K results), by mentioning `kruskal.test(reformulate("Group", x), data = KWR)$p.value`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at `kruskaltests` in the `Rfast` package. For the `KWR` `data.frame`, it appears it would be something like:

```
allKWR <- Rfast::kruskaltests(as.matrix(KWR[,1:124306]), as.numeric(as.factor(KWR$Group)))
```

Comment: Hey, this worked perfectly and quickly. However, my p values are a little bit off compared to the single kruskall wallis tests in R. I don't know how to explain this. Any idea?

Comment: Nevermind, found it :) Thanks a ton, you saved me hours!

Answer (score 0):

This was great - I got 50 columns and several hundred cases in 0.01 system time.